# Delete Record from C# using ManagedInterop

Tags: c#, dynamics-ax-2012

I am working with a C# project that uses the dll, Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop to work with an AX 2012 environment.  From within the code, I need to find a SalesQuotationLine based on specific criteria and delete it. So far, I can get the record I need but I am unable to delete it because I am not using a `TTSBEGIN/TTSCOMMI`T statement and I am not using `FORUPDATE`.   This is my code:

```
DictTable dictTable = new DictTable(Global.tableName2Id("SalesQuotationLine"));
int quotationIdFieldId = (int)dictTable.Call("fieldName2Id", "QuotationId");
int bdcParentRecIdFieldId = (int)dictTable.Call("fieldName2Id", "BDCParentRecId");

var query = new Query();
var datasource = query.addDataSource(Global.tableName2Id("SalesQuotationLine"));
var queryRange1 = datasource.addRange(quotationIdFieldId);
queryRange1.value = "=" + line.QuotationId;            

QueryRun queryRun = new QueryRun(query as object);
while (queryRun.next())
{
    var result = queryRun.get(Global.tableName2Id("SalesQuotationLine"));
    result.Delete();
}
```

I also looked at the code here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197113.aspx but I found that I cannot use it since the code I am working with does not use the .NET Business Connector (I am not sure when one dll should be used over the other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TTSBegin()` and `TTSCommit()` methods on Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop.RuntimeContext.Current. The forUpdate flag can be set by QueryBuildDataSource's `update()`.

It may be easier (and better for maintenance) to write it in an X++ method just call the method from C#.

Comment: I would use X++ but this is deployment code and I have learned that deploying X++ code is a messy at best process.  Especially, when the AX servers have their own code on them.